# Is it true that in New York City there is a special law stating "It is Illegal to break the law"?

Tags: united-states, law

According to the book [Pocket Pal Freaky Facts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1741821215), as published by Hinkler Books Pty Ltd (June 1, 2009), in the section under freaky laws, there is a law in New York City making it illegal to break the law.

Does NYC really have such a dumb (or, perhaps, smart, depending on how you look at it) law?

Comment: Would be funnier to write a law that makes it illegal to obey the law.

Comment: @Evargalo - and would obeying that law be breaking it, or obeying it?

Comment: Just speculation, hence not an answer: when something is declared illegal, a corresponding penalty is included in the law. In this case it would be impossible, since the penalty should depend on the offense. Never heard of a thief sentenced for theft AND for breaking the law. If this sentence is anywhere to be found, it must be as a definition of "illegal", not as a law per ipse.

Comment: Does the book cite the law in question? If so, it should be easy to look up. If not, it's almost certainly an exaggerated claim, if not outright false.

Comment: @phoog it's a kids book. There are zero sources. And there are other claims in the book I know for a fact to be false, such as Mel Blanc was allergic to carrots.

Comment: In that case I wonder whether the claim is sufficiently notable for inclusion here.